# What should I do about my Siamese algae eater fish missing?

Tags: aquarium, fish, lost-pet

I put 1 Siamese algae eater fish in my 10 gallon (38 liters) tank aquascape with no fish yet, last night, until now it's been missing. What should I do?

Comment: What parts do your aquascape have? Any other equipment in the tank? (For possible hides)

Comment: I remove the tree.. still i dont find anywhere, not jumped either. Still a mystery till now

Comment: it is not a good idea to remove parts for long. For example there could be spaces like cracks, where the fish could hide inside, and then is removed with the item from the water. To remove them short time to look them over is okay, but then, for the minimal risk, they should give back to the water

Comment: you should answer the equipment and items part nonetheless, because there are a lots of possibilities nobody can list all. So you help to answer, when you make the possibilities number smaller because we could subtract that, that do not affect your items. Maybe it would be easier for you to add a picture, this would be okay too.